# Run loop command inside shell in groovy

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, groovy

I use the following command which **work as expected**

```
def before(Map<String, String> params) {
  sh """

  make ${params.get('arg')}
  """
}
```

Now I need to modify it a bit to run with loop and I get **complication error**

```
def before(Map<String, String> params) {
  sh """

  params.each{ k, v -> make ${v} }
  """
}
```

Any idea how to resolve this ? I try to add `{` `}` without success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see a compilation error because the body of the string you have passed to `sh` step contains a part that is not recognizable by bash (this part: `params.each{ k, v -> make ${v} }`).

You can tackle this from a different perspective: you can collect all map entries to a list of `make ${arg}` commands, and you can pass it to `sh` step after you join all commands using newline character `\n`. Consider the following example:

```groovy
def before(Map<String, String> map) {
    sh(map.collect { k,v -> "make ${v}" }.join("\n"))
}

before([arg1: "foo", arg2: "bar"])
```

The code that gets executed in `sh` step is an equivalent of something like this:

```groovy
sh """
    make foo
    make bar
"""
```

### Update: executing multiple commands inside `"""` block

If you want to apply the solution shown earlier inside `"""` block you may try to use something like this:

```groovy
def before(Map<String, String> map) {
    sh """

    # Run any command beforehand 

    ${map.collect { k,v -> "make ${v}" }.join(" && ")}
    """
}
```

This approach will allow you to put any bash command before the execution of a chain of commands like

```
make foo && make bar && make 123
```

You could use a different joiner than `&&` (e.g. `\n` like in the previous example). However, chaining commands with `&&` might be better, because if one of them fails it will prevent next commands from running.

Comment: thanks, I've try it like your example but I got error `Also:   groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: v for class: groovy.lang.Binding`

Comment: @shopiaT Try using different argument name than `params` (e.g. `map`). It sounds like Jenkins pipeline picked a global `params` variable or something like that.

Comment: @shopiaT I run this example in my own Jenkins pipeline - naming the parameter `params` or `map` didn't make any difference, both work as expected. I did check in the declarative pipeline as well as in scripted pipeline, with the same result. Your exception suggests that you pass `groovy.lang.Binding` object instead of a `Map`.

Comment: I try to change the name to `map` but still the same issue,  did you use it like `sh """ map.collect { k,v -> "make ${v}" }.join("\\n") """` ?

Comment: Does this runs for you ? i mean in the function ?

Comment: No, this is incorrect. You shouldn't call it like `sh """ map.collect { k,v -> "make ${v}" }.join("\\n") """`, but `sh(map.collect { k,v -> "make ${v}" }.join("\n"))`. The snippet you have shown is incorrect. Please check my answer carefully.

Comment: But the problem is that I've another code with needs to run before in the same context like `cd to folder` etc ,if I run it in another shell it will loose the context , isnt it ?  can you provide example how I can keep the context and use your code ?

Comment: @shopiaT I've updated the answer with an example of running the code inside `"""`.

Comment: Thanks checking it now :)